# Dataframe calculated column not returning numeric values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) which the head looks like:

```
  Quarter   Body    Total requests  Requests on-hold    Total requests received (excluding on-hold)
1 2019_Q3      A                93                 5    
2 2019_Q3      B               228                 2    
3 2019_Q3      C               180                 7    
4 2019_Q3      D                31                 3    
5 2019_Q3      E               555                 0
```

The types of each field are:

```
df.dtypes  
Quarter                                                                                         object
Body                                                                                            object
Total requests                                                                                  object
Requests Processed                                                                              object
Requests on-hold                                                                                object
Total requests received (excluding on-hold)                                                    float64
```

I am trying to calculate `Total requests - Requests on-hold` and inser the result into column `Total requests received (excluding on-hold)` so my desired output would look like:

```
  Quarter   Body    Total requests  Requests on-hold    Total requests received (excluding on-hold)
1 2019_Q3      A                93                 5                                            88
2 2019_Q3      B               228                 2                                           226
3 2019_Q3      C               180                 7                                           173
4 2019_Q3      D                31                 3                                            28
5 2019_Q3      E               555                 0                                           555
```

I am trying to create the Total requests received (excluding on-hold) colum data by using:

```
df['Total requests received (excluding on-hold)'] = df['Total requests'] - df['Requests on-hold']
```

but I get `NaN` for each entry instead of a value

```
  Quarter   Body    Total requests  Requests on-hold    Total requests received (excluding on-hold)
1 2019_Q3      A                93                 5                                           NaN
2 2019_Q3      B               228                 2                                           NaN
3 2019_Q3      C               180                 7                                           NaN
4 2019_Q3      D                31                 3                                           NaN
5 2019_Q3      E               555                 0                                           NaN
```

I noticed that the type for Total requests and Requests on-hold was object so I tried to convert to numeric using

```
df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"])
df["Requests on-hold"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Requests on-hold"])
```

without success. How can I resolve this issue?

NB: when I add the following code to convert to numeric (before the calculation):

```
df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"])
df["Requests on-hold"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Requests on-hold"])
```

I receive the error:

```
    df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"])

  File "C:\Anaconda_Python 3.7\2019.03\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 122, in to_numeric
    raise TypeError('arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series')

TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

Comment: What do you get when using `pd.to_numeric`?

Comment: Hi yatu - I've added the error recieved to the body of the question

Comment: How is `df["Total requests"]` not a `pd.Series`?? Check the dtype

Comment: dtype for df["Total requests"] is object before trying to numeric

Answer (score 0):

It seems some traling whitespaces, so try remove it by `strip`:

```
df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"].str.strip())
df["Requests on-hold"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Requests on-hold"].str.strip())
```

If possible some non numeric values with trailing values first `strip` and then add parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaN`s:

```
df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"].str.strip(), errors='coerce')
df["Requests on-hold"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Requests on-hold"].str.strip(), errors='coerce')
```

And if not trailing whitespaces:

```
df["Total requests"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Total requests"], errors='coerce')
df["Requests on-hold"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Requests on-hold"], errors='coerce')
```